# Query Models through Gorm

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

Here is my Lawyer Model

```
type Lawyer struct {
        ID            uint                 `gorm:"primaryKey" json:"id"`
        FirstName     string               `gorm:"type:varchar(100) not null" json:"first_name"`
        LastName      string               `gorm:"type:varchar(100) not null" json:"last_name"`
        FullName      string               `gorm:"->;type:text GENERATED ALWAYS AS (concat(first_name,' ',last_name)) VIRTUAL;" json:"full_name"`
        LocationID    uint                 `gorm:"not null" json:"location_id"`
        Location      Location             `gorm:"foreignKey:location_id" json:"location"`
        Email         string               `gorm:"unique;not null" json:"email"`
        Phone         string               `gorm:"type:varchar(100);not null" json:"phone"`
        Password      string               `gorm:"type:varchar(100);not null" json:"password"`
        ImageURL      string               `gorm:"type:text" json:"image_url"`
        Education     string               `gorm:"not null" json:"education"`
        Experience    uint                 `gorm:"not null" json:"experience"`
        PracticeAreas []LawyerPracticeArea `gorm:"foreignKey:LawyerID" json:"practice_areas"`
        CreatedAt time.Time `gorm:"" json:"created_at"`
        UpdatedAt time.Time `gorm:"" json:"updated_at"`
    }
```

Here is my LawyerPracticeAreas Model

```
type LawyerPracticeArea struct {
    ID       uint `gorm:"primaryKey" json:"lawyer_practice_area_id"`
    LawyerID uint `gorm:"not null" json:"lawyer_id"`
    PracticeAreaID uint         `gorm:"not null" json:"practice_area_id"`
    PracticeArea   PracticeArea `gorm:"foreignKey:PracticeAreaID" json:"practice_area"`
    Charge         int          `gorm:"" json:"charge"`
    CreatedAt      time.Time    `json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt      time.Time    `json:"updated_at"`
}
```

and last here is my PracticeArea Model

```
type PracticeArea struct {
    ID     uint   `gorm:"primaryKey" json:"practice_area_id"`
    Name   string `gorm:"not null" json:"name"`
    AvgFee string `gorm:"not null" json:"avg_fee"`
}
```

I am querying my Lawyer Model through this:-

```
result := db.Preload(clause.Associations).Find(&lawyer)
```

This result contains all Lawyers and LawyerPracticeAreas data too, but doesn't contain data from PracticeArea table which is inside LawyerPracticeAreas.

Lawyer and PracticeArea have a many-2-many relationship and LawyerPracticeAreas is that table.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjhB3.png]

As you can see I am receiving array of practiceAreas but not the data of that PracticeArea.

Is there any way to query that too in just one query or do I have to iterate through all my lawyers then practiceAreas and then for each id find the practiceArea data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [documentation](https://gorm.io/docs/preload.html#Preload-All):

> `clause.Associations` won’t preload nested associations, but you can use it with Nested Preloading together...

In your case, to load everything, even the associations nested more than one level deep, you could do this:

```
result := db.Preload("Location").Preload("PracticeAreas.PracticeArea").Find(&lawyer)
```